# WebDriver : Automated Code Generation without using Selenium IDE

Tags: java, dom, webdriver, html-parsing, selenium-webdriver

My Companys website is compatible only with IE. So i cannot use IDE for recording webdriver scripts.
There are HTML pages which has about 100 or 200(not exact count) of textboxes and Dropdowns.

Writing java code to automate this is very much tedious.

Can someone provide me with tool or utility to read the HTML file itself and generate the corresponding code ?
Or guide me how to develop a utility to meet my need ?

For example :

Consider an html file like this

```
<html>
<body>
<input name = "employee_name" />
<select id = "designation">
<option value = "MD">MD</option>
<option value = "programmer"> Programmer </option>
<option value = "CEO"> CEO </option>
</option>

<body>
</html>
```

If i give this file as input to utility it will generate me a java file like this

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

WebElement employee_name = driver.findElement(By.name("employee_name"));
employee_name.sendKeys("...");

Select designation = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("designation")));
designation.selectByVisibleText("...");
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I have been looking out for such an implementation too. I came across this: [Self-Generating Test Artifacts for Selenium/WebDriver](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mSCFsUOgPpw)         Didn't really understand how they did it.

Comment: The code used for that presentation is: https://github.com/mmerrell/tastymonster

Comment: Try [this](http://fire-ie-selenium.googlecode.com/files/Fire-IEBrowser1.4.xlsm)
It can be of some help.

Comment: I'd add that if you can find a tool that does this, reliably, I wouldn't use it anyway - the record & playback concept is very bad. Yes, automating all this is tedious, but it will pay off....and perhaps the reason for no IE plugin to do this is that IE's plugin architecture is rubbish or lacking in documentation.

Comment: There isn't a tool existing in human world yet, which can auto generate maintainable and elegant UI testing code like a senior developer. You may find it easier to record tests, but you will realize how bad it gets when you start maintaining them.

Comment: @Arran and user1177636 Yes i do agree with your statements. I am following page object pattern to create test scripts. I also understand the advantages of using it.

However i need this tool to generate code for about 100 fields on my page. The code once generated will be fit into page object architecture. I need this just to reduce my effort.

Comment: @Hemche how to use it ? Can you please explain

Comment: @AbhishekSingh You need to open the excel sheet and enable macros. Once, a window is opened, you need to open your application inside that. Right click on whichever field you need and give a name in the text box that appears for recognition. Repeat the same activity for all the fields. Once it is done, you can see an excel sheet populated with different locators for all the fields. Hope it helps to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using "Selenium Builder" rather than "Selenium IDE", BUT, in theory, you could get all similar elements from a page in a group like so:

```
List<WebElement> bodyinputs = driver
       .findElements( By.xpath("//div[@class='body']/input") );
List<WebElement> footeranchors = driver
       .findElements( By.xpath("//div[@class='footer']/a") );
```

Then, for each  of these groups, you can loop through the lists and use a JavaScriptExecutor to evaluate and figure out the XPath for each element and store the XPath in a hashtable with each Element:

```
protected String getXPath() { 
        String jscript = "function getPathTo(node) {" + 
            "  var stack = [];" + 
            "  while(node.parentNode !== null) {" + 
            "    stack.unshift(node.tagName);" + 
            "    node = node.parentNode;" + 
            "  }" + 
            "  return stack.join('/');" + 
            "}" + 
            "return getPathTo(arguments[0]);"; 
        return (String) driver.executeScript(jscript, webElement); 
    }
```

Then, the final step, you can auto-generate "By locators" using the HashTable as input.

But even if you do that you still need to write code to intelligently figure out which By locators get which inputs and which ones don't.